# Pass variable name into function?

Tags: python, function

I have a function that contains several variables, but I only want to run it for one variable at the time. For example only for "exrate". The idea is to pass "exrate" into the function and then for-loop "exrate" only and calculate the result. Unfortunately the the value "turnover" does not change.

```
exrate = 100
sales = 0

def sim(var, min, max):
    for var in range(min, max):
        turnover = 1000 * (exrate/100) + sales
        print(turnover)

sim(exrate, 100, 105)
sim(sales, 1000, 1100)
```

Comment: Not sure what your expected output is or what you want?

Comment: Where is `turnover` defined?  the variable `var` is `exrate` inside the function.  You may first need to clean up variable names.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `self.exrate` and `self.sales` in the function you define?

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: Your current function doesn't use the `var` argument it's passed because it creates a local variable of the same name. What would you want the function to _do_ with the variable (or variable name) it's passed?

Comment: The idea was to pass exrate into the function (var = exrate). And then loop exrate (=var). Output should be: 1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040.

Comment: When I replace var with exrate, it is working. But what if I then want to use the same function for "sales"? Instead of writing a function for each variable, I would like to only one function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to refactor your original code a bit:

```
exrate = 100
sales = 0

def sim(var, min, max):
    for var in range(min, max):
        turnover = 1000 * (exrate/100) + sales
        print(turnover)
```

First, we can factor out the function used in sim, which would be:

```
def f(exrate, sales):
    return 1000 * (exrate/100) + sales
```

and that function can be simplified further `1000/100=10`:

```
def f(exrate, sales):
    return 10 * exrate + sales
```

You're using globals `exrate=100, sales=0` but that's not a good idea, so lets' get rid of those globals by just using default parameters:

```
def f(exrate=100, sales=0):
    return 10 * exrate + sales
```

Now, at this point we've got a mathy function we can use as input to another functions, it's a function with one single responsability.

So let's say we want to see how this function evolves with respect to one of its independent variables `(exrate or sales)`:

```
for i in range(100, 1000, 100):
    print(f(exrate=i))

for i in range(0, 1000, 200):
    print(f(sales=i))
```

Or both:

```
for i in range(0, 1000, 200):
    print(f(exrate=200, sales=i))
```

The main idea would be, when simulating something is a good idea to split the code into code that does the simulation (plotting the function in a graph, print values onto a console, ...) and the code which is the simulation itself (in this case, a [simple linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) of the form `f(x)=ax+b`)

Comment: Thank you and also for the good explanation! My issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable external to the function in the definition. Consider replacing exrate with var within the function definition.